# How do I stack an image on to an existing background in javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx, background-image

Here are the approaches that I've tried. I've tried to use imageView, set the image to it and added it to stackpane. The image come out rather large and doesn't look how I want the main menu to look like(The background color is there when I maximized the screen but the logoIcon initially takes over the whole screen). Then I decided to get rid of that, use a styleclass and add it to my stackpane but it doesn't seem to register the styleclass that I added to the stackpane. Since this is simple example, you can try out the program and see what you get.

Here is the relevant code

```
package whowantstobeamillionairetriviagame;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame extends Application 
{   
@Override
public void start(Stage startingStage) throws Exception
{    
    Image backgroundColor = new Image("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-p0s06MBIx_U/T8zKIBZ24pI/AAAAAAAAA7Y/n8hMZfpRic0/s1600/dark+blue+wallpaper+10.jpg");

    BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(100, 100, true, true, true, true);
    BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, 
    BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

    StackPane background = new StackPane();
    background.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));
    background.getStyleClass().add("MillionaireLogo");

    Scene backgroundScene = new Scene(background);
    startingStage.setScene(backgroundScene);

    startingStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

MillionaireLogo.css file

```
 .MillionaireLogo
{
  -fx-background-image: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ujgaiwveDzc/TZQeK9gZvPI/AAAAAAAAADY/ZNVAxlaqXoY/s1600/Millionaire%2BParody%2BLogo2%2Bcopy.jpg");
  -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -fx-background-position: top center;
  -fx-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a solution that solves my main problem(stacking an image to the background)

```
package whowantstobeamillionairetriviagame;

import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame extends Application 
{   
@Override
public void start(Stage startingStage) throws Exception
{      
    StackPane backgroundSettings = new StackPane();

    Image backgroundColor = new Image("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-p0s06MBIx_U/T8zKIBZ24pI/AAAAAAAAA7Y/n8hMZfpRic0/s1600/dark+blue+wallpaper+10.jpg");

    ImageView background = new ImageView();
    background.setImage(backgroundColor);

    Image millionaireLogo = new Image(new File("MillionaireLogo.PNG").toURI().toString());

    ImageView logoPicture = new ImageView();
    logoPicture.setImage(millionaireLogo);
    logoPicture.setPreserveRatio(true);
    logoPicture.setSmooth(true);
    logoPicture.setCache(true);
    StackPane.setAlignment(logoPicture, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    backgroundSettings.getChildren().addAll(background, logoPicture);

    Scene backgroundScene = new Scene(backgroundSettings);
    startingStage.setScene(backgroundScene);

    startingStage.setTitle("Who Wants to be a Millionaire");
    startingStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

My new problem now is how can I shrink the size of the image(given the code that I have) and place it at the top center of the screen?

Comment: Oh and I got rid of the CSS file

Comment: Also, how can I remove the white spaces around the image?

Comment: Alright I was able to center the image to the top center using this line of code  StackPane.setAlignment(logoPicture, Pos.TOP_CENTER); Now all I need to do is resize the image to a proper size and get rid of the white spaces.

Comment: I've gotten the program to look almost perfect. All that is left to do is to remove those white spaces. Any ideas?

Comment: Please create a new question, if you have one.